# facebook batch request with jsonpath

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, jsonpath, facebook-batch-request

With Facebook, i need to know, who (which user) has commented on a post on a facebook-page.
I make two requests with facebook-batch-requests in my javascript-file, the first for all the posts and with the second, I want the requests of each post. Nice to have, if i can choose just the posts which have some comments.

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
  batch: [
  {
    // all posts from page from last year
    'method': 'GET',
    'name': 'posts_page_year',
    'omit_response_on_success': false,
    'relative_url': fbPageID + '/posts?since=2012-01-01&until=' + timeNow + '&limit=200000'
  },
  {
    // all post-ids from last year
    'method': 'GET',
    "relative_url": "/{result=posts_page_year:$.data.*.id[?(@.comments.count!=0)]}"
  }
]
}, function(response) {
  callback(response);
}
);
```

My problem is the second batch-request, it returns an error (#803). I tried out a little bit.

```
{
    // all post-ids from last year
    'method': 'GET',
    "relative_url": "/{result=posts_page_year:$.data.0.id}"
}
```

returns an object with the first post-request. Everything is Good. But I want this of every Post, not just the first one.

```
{
    // all post-ids from last year
    'method': 'GET',
    "relative_url": "/{result=posts_page_year:$.data.*.id}"
}
```

returns an error (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist and a list of all ID's.

```
{
    // all post-ids from last year
    'method': 'GET',
    "relative_url": "/{result=posts_page_year:$.data.*.id[?(@.comments.count!=0)]}"
}
```

returns this error:
(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {result=posts_page_year:$.data.*.id[

I tried out nearly everything and need your help cause I don't know how to fix the problem. THX!

Comment: I have solved the problem. But at the moment, i can't remember - it's long time ago. If somebody is interested in the solution, please add a comment.

Comment: Hello, i'm interested in the solution :)

Comment: Hi @Morti, You can read the solution in my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26582946/2241151).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Facebook [batch documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), it states:

> Note that for security reasons filter and script JSONPath constructs
>   are not allowed in the JSONPath expression.

This probably means you can't use code like `?(@.comments.count!=0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
  batch: [
    {
      // 0: all likes from user
      'method': 'GET',
      'relative_url': 'me/likes'
    },
    {
      // 1: all user-posts from last month
      'method': 'GET',
      'relative_url': 'me/posts?since=' + timeMonthAgo + '&until=' + timeNow + '&limit=200000'
    },
    {
      // 2: all user-posts from last year
      'method': 'GET',
      'relative_url': 'me/posts?since=' + timeYearAgo + '&until=' + timeNow + '&limit=200000'
    }
  ]
  }, function (response) {
    callback(response);
  }
);
```

I had to set a Limit, so that each response has now a limit of content. It is possible to set the limit to an impossible large number. You have to set a time-range too with the `since` and `until` parameters.

I hope this helps somebody.